# Linear continuous functional that is not uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'd like to know, Is there an linear(additive), continuous, homogeneous, functional that is not uniformly continuous? What are the advantages if there isn't one.

Comment: A linear map between two normed spaces (or locally convex spaces or even topological vector spaces) which is continuous at some point is already uniformly continuous. This is quite elementary and can be found in many text books of functional analysis.

Comment: @Jochen : The vector metric space, described in this paper page 425. and rest of paper.  http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1936-040-03/S0002-9947-1936-1501882-8/S0002-9947-1936-1501882-8.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need some compatibility of the metric and the vector space structure to obtain uniform continuity from continuity (at $0$). Here is a simple example showing that, in general, continuity and uniform continuity of linear maps are different: Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and $f:X\to Y$, $f(x)=x$. 
Consider on $Y$ the usual metric $|x-y|$ and on $X$ the metric 
$$d(x,y)=|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|$$
where $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is any strictly increasing continuous and bounded function, e.g $\varphi(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ or $\varphi=\arctan$.
Then, the identity is continuous (because $\varphi$ has a continuous inverse) but it is not uniformly continuous because $d(n,n+1)\to 0$ and $|n-(n+1)|\not\to 0$.

This example shows that although $X$ and $Y$ have the same topology they are quite different: $Y$ is complete but $X$ is not.